# Viewing images in a window using C Program?

Tags: c, image, optimization, opencv

I am trying to develop a YUV image viewer. The objective is it read YUV images and displays the image in a window.I am using C to develop this application.

After transforming YUV information to RGB data, to view the image i am using cvShowImage and cvResize functions from OpenCV. To use this application in other systems i need opencv to be installed in them as i am using precompiled dll's. I fixed this issue by re-compiling the program with static libraries basing on the guide provided in "[How to embedd openCV Dll's in Executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579535/how-to-embedd-opencv-dlls-in-executable%22)" and generated a fresh executable which is portable across machines. This resulted my application file size to grow from 100KB to 2350KB. This growth is enormous. I suspect this is because of several unnecessary functions are getting linked to my final executable

for this i used the switch Eliminate Unreferenced Data (/OPT:REF). But this did not solve anything.

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The linker automatically removes all the unneeded code from you exe.

But if you remember that your program incorporates

- all the code to read all kinds of image formats (bmp, jpg, tiff, etc, etc, etc),
- a good part of the OpenCV core (matrix handling)
- some OS-specific windowing and message handling (to display the image and be able to resize/click/etc)
- some other utilities that you use and do not know

That's it... a few MB of code.

**EDIT**

Do not forget to build your program in Release mode. In Debug mode, to the standard code there is added some more info related to debugging.

Comment: @ vasile: I compiled the code in release mode. That changed the size but the reduction is not impressive. My program is not using any pre-defined functions in libraries. The only thing it is accessing is cvShowImage. I don't see how this function is need of png, jpg libraries. I believe they need to be excluded. But i sense it is not happening. The application as such in release mode is 30Kb but including opencv lib's has made it to 1830Kb.

Comment: You say you need to load an image - it is not clear where do you take it from (file or camera) but whatever you use to load that image, it's a lot of code you are not aware of. And there are other things you use, but you do not think of, like std library, or many other useful programming tools, that add to your lib size.

Comment: @vasile: I developed a software which decodes jpeg images. I read jpeg image in normal bin format in to memory and then i decode the image and i attain raw pixels. Now i want to view these raw pixels in a window. So i do not use any predefined loadimage function. I actually develop the loadimage function on my own.

Comment: What makes you think that the list I wrote in the andswer must vanish, just because you do not use a jpeg decoder? And if you did not wrote the whole jpeg decoding from scratch, in pure cpp, without any library calls, including DCT, and other such things, you actually **call** a jpeg library, which adds size to the exe .

Comment: If i am not calling any of the functions in the library wont they be automatically removed from the final exe as part of optimization (unreachable code)? forgive me i am not clear about how the linking works...

Comment: You do not understand that you actually *call* them. The OpenCV stuff uses a lot of libraries behind, even if you think it's just *one function call*. It has a lot of branches for all kinds of formats. It looks like a few lines of code for you, but behind is an elephant. You do not see any call for jpeg libs, or system libs, or error checking, but all of them are there, making part of the language support, library support, system support, etc. If you want a small program, write **everything** from scratch, even printf, and camera drivers, and screen printing routines, etc.